# ORACLE SQL CAST IN CASE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, integer, case

Is there a way to CAST as an INTEGER within a CASE Statement ?

```
CASE 
WHEN SV.END_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN SV.END_DATE - SV.START_DATE 
ELSE 0
END AS DAYDIFF
```

Comment: What are you trying to do - round, or truncate, the difference between `end_date` and `start_date`? Get the number of whole days between them? or something else? Sample data and expected results might make things clearer too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could [cast](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CAST.html) the value to a numeric data type with no fractional part:

```
CASE 
  WHEN SV.END_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN
    CAST(SV.END_DATE - SV.START_DATE AS NUMBER(38))
  ELSE 0
END AS DAYDIFF
```

or you could [truncate the result](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRUNC-number.html), which also strips the fractional part of the value:

```
CASE 
  WHEN SV.END_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN
    TRUNC(SV.END_DATE - SV.START_DATE)
  ELSE 0
END AS DAYDIFF
```

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate your support.